# returning error message to front end Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to send an error status to the front end using Scala play. Ok is to say all is ok but which one is for error? Can this be done from any Scala method I created?
thanks

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActions this shows a few of the ways to send an http error.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done from any method, you just need to use correspondent `Result`. For the general server error it is `InternalServerError`like

```
def index = Action {
  InternalServerError("Some error happens")
}
```

You can find more results here: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.7/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Results

The examples are:

```
InsufficientStorage  //507
Locked  //423
```

You can also send your own state as simple as

```
new Status(500) //aka InternalServerError
```